# Can make custom comparator such as "caseInsensitiveCompare" in sorting?

Tags: objective-c

I trying to sort some data to use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method in an `NSArray` class.

That method must need to indicate standard comparator, but I want to indicate custom comparator what I make.

Is possible?

Here is part of my sorting code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor =
[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
  initWithKey:FIRSTNAME
  ascending:YES
  selector:@selector(CustomCompare:)] autorelease];
```

`CustomCompare:` <= want to make custom comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and implement your comparator to be case-insensitive?  Something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSString *str1 = (NSString *)o1;
    NSString *str2 = (NSString *)o2;

    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

**update**

For more complex classes, multiple comparison fields may also be used:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    MyClass *cl1 = (MyClass *)o1;
    MyClass *cl2 = (MyClass *)o2;

    NSComparisonResult result = [cl1.primaryString compare:cl2.primaryString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        result = [cl1.secondaryString compare:cl2.secondaryString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];        
    }
    return result;
}];
```

Comment: reason of using sortedArrayUsingComparator: is can mutisort.

Comment: @user868754 - Assuming you mean sort by more than one key, you can accomplish the same thing in your comparator.

Comment: when a class has various member variable, can sort by multi condition.

Comment: @user868754 - Previous comment still applies.  I'll update my answer with an example.